# Bad results using Hopfield network

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

Im writing a program that will recognize traffic signs using neural networks and I have a problem with `Hopfield` network. I'm using [this example](http://www.massapi.com/source/encog-java-read-only/encog-examples/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/neural/hopfield/HopfieldAssociate.java.html) to make my own hopfield network.

As an input, I use those traffic signs after normalization and it's a 50x50 matrix of `0` and `1`.

The problem that I encounter is that when Hopfield network will learn 2 patterns it recognize them well, but when I try to train it with more than 2 patterns as a result it gives me a pattern that isn't matching any of those that it was trained on and it returns it for any input that I provide.

Here is my code, quite similar to the one from official encog examples:

```
public BiPolarNeuralData convertPattern(double[][] data, int index)
{
    int resultIndex = 0;
    BiPolarNeuralData result = new BiPolarNeuralData(WIDTH*HEIGHT);
    for(int i=0;i<(WIDTH*HEIGHT);i++)
    {
        boolean znak=true;
        if(data[index][i]==1)znak=true;
        else znak=false;
        result.setData(resultIndex++,data[index][i]==1.0);
    }

    return result;
}

public void display(BiPolarNeuralData pattern1,BiPolarNeuralData pattern2)
{
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    for(int row = 0;row<HEIGHT;row++)
    {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

        for(int col = 0;col<WIDTH;col++)
        {
            if(pattern1.getBoolean(index1++))
                line.append('O');
            else
                line.append(' ');
        }

        line.append("   ->   ");

        for(int col = 0;col<WIDTH;col++)
        {
            if(pattern2.getBoolean(index2++))
                line.append('O');
            else
                line.append(' ');
        }

        System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
}


public void evaluate(HopfieldNetwork hopfieldLogic, double[][] pattern)
{
    for(int i=0;i<pattern.length;i++)
    {
        BiPolarNeuralData pattern1 = convertPattern(pattern,i);
        hopfieldLogic.setCurrentState(pattern1);
        int cycles = hopfieldLogic.runUntilStable(100);
        BiPolarNeuralData pattern2 = hopfieldLogic.getCurrentState();
        System.out.println("Cycles until stable(max 100): " + cycles + ", result=");
        display( pattern1, pattern2);
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }
}

public BasicNetwork trainHopfieldNetwork(){
    HopfieldNetwork hopfieldLogic = new HopfieldNetwork(HEIGHT*WIDTH);

    for(int i=0;i<inputData.length;i++)
    {
        hopfieldLogic.addPattern(convertPattern(inputData,i));
        System.out.println("Pattern : "+i);
    }

    evaluate(hopfieldLogic,inputData);

    return null;
}
```

Where `inputData` is an `array[2500]` of type `double`.

What I've tried so far is:

1. Changing size of patterns to be smaller (10x10, 20x20).
2. Trying to learn different numbers of patterns (from 2 to 20). I always get strange results that don't match any of patterns that network was trained on.

Answer (score 1):

So afterall the problem was the learning rule of network, since encog framework has implemented only hebb learning rule that isn't quite usefull for complex networks i had to implement pseudoinversion learning rule, and after that hopfield network started to recognize patterns without troubles